# How to access properties of an object that is bind by the calling component in angular?

Tags: angular

component definition:

````
...
...= {'a':1}
```
````

in the template:

```
...
{{test|json}}
{{test.a}}
...
```

output:

```
{ "a": 1 }
```

Everything is right. But I want to bind the property test from another component:

component definition:

```
...
@Input()
test = {}
...
```

in the root component/template:

```
...
<test-component [test]="{'a':1}"></test-component>
...
```

in the template:

```
...
{{test|json}}
...
```

output:

```
{ "a": 1 }
```

in the template:

```
...
{{test|json}}
{{test.a}}
...
```

output:

```
**ERROR:  error TS2339: Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'**
```

Why is the property `a` not accessable and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe it'll help to type your `@Input()` like `@Input() test: any = {};`

Comment: yes, that helps. I don't know why.

Comment: @testo: With Ivy enabled, strict type checking for templates are enabled. Without a defined type like `any`, Ivy cannot determine the property `a` in the object.

Comment: thanks. I think setting a type for everything might be a good idea.

Comment: If you are passing this object down components, you likely know what it looks like and you should probably define it using an interface. Using 'any' is just a workaround.

Comment: in my case, it is a hierarchical structure. It contains some data and an elements-array. I pass down one element from that array ... and the component calls itself.